# Find the elements only after a specific text in html using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Lets say I have following HTML Code

```html
<div class="12"> 
  <div class="something"></div> 
</div>
<div class="12"> 
  <div class="34"> 
    <span>TODAY</span> 
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="12"> 
  <div class="something"></div> 
</div> 
<div class="12"> 
  <div class="something"></div> 
</div>
```

Now If I use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("something")` then I get all the classes present in the HTML code. But I want to get classes only after a specific word ("Today") in HTML. How to exclude classes that appear before the specific word. Next divs and classes could be at any level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use search by XPath as below:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*/text()[.="some specific word"]/following-sibling::div[@class="something"]')
```

Note that you might need some modifications in case your *real* HTML differs from provided *simplified* HTML

*Update*

replace `following-sibling` with `following` if required `div` nodes are not siblings:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*/text()[.="some specific word"]/following::div[@class="something"]')
```

Comment: actually, next divs are not siblings, they can be at any level.

Comment: And how can I guess it? This should be reflected in your question

Comment: sorry for that, now edited. Can now help me out with that?

Comment: `<div class="12">
 <div class="34">
  <span>TODAY</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="12">
 <div class="target_class"></div>
</div>
<div class="12">
 <div class="target_class"></div>
</div>` 
This is the actual structure of HTML. My word is "TODAY" and the class I am looking for is "Target_class". I tried with following but not working.

Comment: Now working fine. We will need to use the name of all the classes associated with the div.